# meaning of もったり

Tags: meaning

don't understand meaning of もったり 　
Just want to draw attention to its use in a sentence:
・・・の方がもったりしていたり・・・だったりする。
so I doubt there is implied something like 持ったり

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「もったり」 ≠ 「[持]{も}ったり」

There is nothing in common between those two.  The meaning is completely different and so is the pronunciation.  The pitch accent is on the 「た」 in 「もったり」 and 「も」 in 「持ったり」.

「もったり」 is an adverb describing, for instance, the texture of whipped cream.  "**Sticky liquid**", "**glutinous**", etc. would come to mind.

It can also mean "**dull**" or "**slow-moving**" depending on the context.

Note that regardless of how you translate it, it is an **adverb** in Japanese.